# Text skipping a page in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, paragraph-styles

While working on an Indesign document, my text skips a page for no apparent reason, could somebody please clarify why? When I delete the space between words, the text returns to the same page, but as soon as I insert a space between words, the text skips a page and goes to the next one, leaving a blank page.
Could it be connected with the Keep options I'm using and how can I fix it?
Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm afraid there is nowhere near enough information for anyone to know what is going on here. How are your pages set up? I'm assuming you have threaded text frames on each page? When does the text skip a page? Is there anything else on the page that is being skipped?

Comment: Even with a screenshot of your file, it is probably going to be impossible to answer this. There are a gazillion reasons why text might skip: an element with a text wrap, a hard 'new page', a bug...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to try:

Create a new document. Make sure it's not set up as Facing Pages. Try importing your text into that. If that works, it was something in your document.

Copy all your text into a bare-bones editor like BBEdit or Text Wrangler, which will strip out ALL formatting and styling. Paste that into a new IND document. If that works, it was something in your paragraph styling.

Comment: Thank you a lot, doing the thing with the new document helped :)

Comment: @JohnSmith Thanks! If my answer was useful to you, please click the up arrow to upvote it, and if it was the right answer, please click the checkmark to accept it. That's how the Stack exchange interface works. :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Primary Text Frame (File -> Document Setup...)? Possible you accidentally deleted the text frame from the page that's being skipped.

Comment: Sorry, it definitely isn't a problem with a primary text frame, when i hit return once, the text returns to normal, but when i want to insert space between words the text doesn't move to to next page, but to the one after, leaving a blank page for some reason I cant figure out